# Service restarted on Android

Tags: android, android-service

I've created a service:

```
public class ActivityService extends Service {

    private static StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
    private long tid;
    private GPSMonitor gps;
    private Context ctx;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    private NotificationManager nm;
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

        if (workIntent == null)
            return;

        int state = workIntent.getIntExtra("state", -1);

        Log.d("bla", isRunning + "");
        Log.d("bla", state + "");
        if (state == 0)
        {
            if (isRunning)
                return;

            tid = workIntent.getLongExtra("tid", 0);

            isRunning = true;

        }
        else if (state == 1)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (state == 2)
        {
            ....
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        ctx = this;
        onHandleIntent(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

and in my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track);

        Log.d("bla", "create");
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        reMyreceive=new Myreceiver();


        Intent i= new Intent(this, ActivityService.class);
        i.putExtra("tid", 123);
        i.putExtra("state", 0);
        startService(i);
```

All is good except the following scenario:
1. The service is started.
2. I go out of the activity (Paused)
3. I browse in 5-6 different apps.
4. Going back to the activity via a generated notification from the service.
5. The activity will go onCreate, hence will do startService.
6. The service is created from scratch. (isRunning = false! even though it was true...)

I am trying to keep the service persistent. this is made for GPS running app.
and it seems to me as if when i browse different apps in my device, the android decides to onCreate my activity (which is fine) but the service is restarted from scratch!

How can I maintain this to be as persistent as possible?

Thanks